# Error in running the Angular 7 app with Node Js LTS 16.13.2

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, angular7

I am running angular 7 app with below docker file with node:16.13.2 LTS

```
FROM node:16.13.2
ENV context ""
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src/
COPY . /usr/src/
RUN npm install
ENV context ""
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "--", "start", "--serve-path=${context}/"]
```

I am using this command to run this app :

```
docker run -p 3008:3000 -e context=/a7 myImageName
```

now If I access that in browser I get following message.

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ VM214:6774
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this Issue?

- thank you

Answer (score 2):

I solved it and could resolve this issue.
below is my old package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 3010 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check true",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner",
    "test:jest": "jest ./src/app"
  },
```

below is my updated package.json (just updated the port to 3000 and it worked)

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 3000 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check true",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner",
    "test:jest": "jest ./src/app"
  },
```

Looks like port was being used as from package.json not from dockerfile. so it has utilised the port mentioned in package.json.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. After changing the port from `1624` to `3000`, the issue was resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).